# How to display numeric json arrays horizontally in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I saved a json file in Visual Studio Code, it automatically formats the document, that arrays are displayed vertically (by adding line breaks). Since I have giant integer arrays, it makes a quick look into the file nearly impossible. Example:

```
{
    "big_integer_array": [
        12,
        15,
        13,
        1,
        5,
        8,
        15,
        14,
        12,
        ...
    ],
    "this_value_is_in_line_million": true
}
```

How can I tell the program, to display numeric arrays horizontally like this:

```
{
    "big_integer_array": [12,15,13,1,5,8,15,14,12, ...],
    "this_value_is_in_line_three": true
}
```

### **Solution**

1. Use the extension esbenp.prettier-vscode
2. Set the prettier.printwidth to 99999999999

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new setting built-in to vscode v1.70 specifically for this situation:

```
JSON > Format: Keep Lines  <= enable this in your Settings
"json.format.keepLines": true <= or use that setting in your settings.json
```

> This feature allows one to keep the initial line positions upon line
> formatting of JSON documents. For example an array containing values
> on one line will still contain these values on the same line after
> formatting. To enable this feature, enable the option `JSON > Format: Keep Lines` in the settings.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#keep-newlines-when-formatting-json

Demo using the Insiders Build - first without the setting enabled and then after enabling the setting:

[image: JSON formatting keep lines demo]

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to customize the VS Code native formatter to format arrays in the way you suggest, however, the prettier formatter will configure them as you suggest. Prettier is a widely used formatter, and is used by a good majority of VS Code users.

The ID for the official prettier extension is: `esbenp.prettier-vscode`

It's important to note that **Prettier** will take care of arrays that have a single type of input for you. So if an array is all numbers, or all strings, however; if an array consist of mixed types, numbers, objects, arrays in arrays, strings, boolean values, etc...
Then the way prettier formats the array is contingent on how you place the brackets initially.

---

#### Formatting Mixed arrays with Prettier

---

*For this example's sake, lets say have the following array in a json file.*

```
{
  "obj": {
    "Array": [
      "Apple",
      "Broccoli",
      "Coconut",
      "Orange",
      "Carrot",
      {
          "foo": "apple"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

If you change the brackets in the array, so that the array looks like the following:

```
{
  "obj": {
    "Array": [
      "Apple",
      "Broccoli",
      "Coconut",
      "Orange",
      "Carrot",
      {"foo": "apple"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Your basically telling prettier that you don't want to break up your embedded objects and arrays vertically, but rather, you want to keep them horizontally. Formatting the example above (using **prettier**) will result in your file looking like the example below:

```
{
  "obj": {
    "Array": ["Apple", "Broccoli", "Coconut", "Orange", "Carrot", { "foo": "apple" }]
  }
}
```

However, if you format your array like this:

```
{
  "obj": {
    "Array": ["Apple", "Broccoli", "Coconut", "Orange", "Carrot", {
         "foo": "apple" 
         }]
  }
```

Then when you format the above example using prettier, you will produce the output below:

```
{
  "obj": {
    "Array": [
      "Apple",
      "Broccoli",
      "Coconut",
      "Orange",
      "Carrot",
      {
        "foo": "apple"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also note than the following settings in your **VS Code's** `settings.json` file can affect how prettier formats JSON as well:

1. `"prettier.useTabs": true|false` (says to use tab, or spaces)
2. `"prettier.tabWidth": Numeric Value` (Sets tab spacing qty)
3. `"prettier.printWidth": Numeric Value` (Sets line length)
4. `"prettier.bracketSpacing": True|False` (Adds/Removes spacing in brackets)

Comment: Thanks, that looks half perfect. Strangely the formatter did a good job on int arrays, but handle strings and floats like the original JSON formatter. Any idea how I can adjust that?

Comment: Oh, so for string arrays you have... Here I am going to post it in the answer, one sec

Comment: Ah just realized that there is another problem. The extension doesn't print the array fully inline. After the array holds a certain amount of elements, the formatter breaks it to the next line. See updated question

Comment: So for arrays that contain just strings, prettier should format fine, but if you have an object with an array of strings in it, then that is considered a mixed object, or an array with strings and numbers would be a mixed array. In the case of a mixed item, prettier formats depending on how you initially placed the brackets for the mixed item. I provided an example above.

Comment: Also, prettier will break up an array if it exceeds the value set for the prettier.printwidth setting. You can find out more about configuring prettier at prettier.io

Comment: prettier.printwidth did the job for me! I set it to 9999999 and now it works like desired. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Okay, Great! You can also configure prettier via a `.prettierrc` file. Which is actually the suggested method. I suggest you check out this page https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: Happy coding mate!